# How to install cloudera on top of apache hadoop 2.7.1

Tags: apache, hadoop, cloudera-manager

I am currently working on apache hadoop2.7.1, cluster includes 1 name node and 3 data nodes.

Is it possible to install cloudera manager on existing apache hadoop 2.7.1 cluster. If yes, could you please suggest me how it can be done.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

No, that is not possible. It goes the other way around. You install Cloudera Manager, and then you deploy Hadoop components from its web console.

Comment: Note that latests versions of Cloudera still ship Hadoop 2.6 so even with this approach you won't have a Cloudera with Hadoop 2.7.